# Parsing unknown list object

Tags: python, boto

I am using Amazon's MWS boto API to pull orders, but I'm having trouble parsing the results. Other APIs I've used return XML data, but boto does not. In boto, if you call:

`boto.set_stream_logger('boto')`

It will print the XML data to the console, but I can't find any function that returns XML data so I need to deal with what they give me.

Here is how I am pulling the orders:

`orders = mws.list_orders(**params)`

This is the type of `orders`:

`<class 'boto.mws.response.ListOrdersResponse'>`

This is a sample of what `orders` will contain: (Formatting is mine, for clarity. Originally, it will have no line-breaks)

```
ListOrdersResponse{u'xmlns': u'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01'}

(ListOrdersResult: ListOrdersResult{}

    (CreatedBefore: u'xxxx', Orders: ^Orders^{}

        (Order: [

            Order{}(LatestDeliveryDate: u'xxxx', LatestShipDate: u'xxxx',
            FulfillmentChannel: u'xxxx', ShippingAddress: ^ShippingAddress^{}(City: u'xxxx', 
            Name: u'xxxx', CountryCode: u'xxxx', Phone: u'xxxx', StateOrRegion: u'xxxx', 
            AddressLine1: u'xxxx', PostalCode: u'xxxx'), EarliestDeliveryDate: u'xxxx', 
            PurchaseDate: u'xxxx', ShipmentServiceLevelCategory: u'xxxx', 
            OrderTotal: USD 23.12, AmazonOrderId: u'xxxx', EarliestShipDate: u'xxxx', 
            NumberOfItemsUnshipped: u'xxxx', OrderStatus: u'xxxx', IsBusinessOrder: u'xxxx', 
            OrderType: u'xxxx', PaymentExecutionDetail: None, ShippedByAmazonTFM: u'xxxx', 
            PaymentMethod: u'xxxx', SalesChannel: u'xxxx', LastUpdateDate: u'xxxx', 
            BuyerEmail: u'xxxx', ShipServiceLevel: u'xxxx', BuyerName: u'xxxx', 
            NumberOfItemsShipped: u'xxxx', MarketplaceId: u'xxxx'), 

            # Other orders similar to above

        ])

    ), 

ResponseMetadata: ^ResponseMetadata^{}(RequestId: u'xxxx'))
```

For reference, [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/develop/boto/mws) on github:  [ListOrdersResult](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/mws/response.py#L642) which implements [Element](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/mws/response.py#L73) and [ElementList](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/mws/response.py#L94).

**QUESTION SUMMARY:**

1. Is this a specific python structure? It seems like a list crossed with a dictionary. I think this might be some kind of unicode or JSON dictionary, but I'm not familiar with python and can't tell yet.
2. How can I parse through a large number of orders using this data structure? I would want to go into each individual order item, and pull certain fields, such as `BuyerName`.

I've tried calling `orders.ListOrdersResult.CreatedBefore` and it will return the value `xxxx` from `CreatedBefore: u'xxxx'`. So far I haven't been able to get further. Calling something like `ListOrdersResult.Order` or similar will throw an `AttributeError.`

3. For anyone familiar with boto, is it possible to somehow return XML data from this function `boto.set_stream_logger('boto')`? Python has many libraries to deal with XML data easily.

Thank you in advance! There is very little documentation on Amazon's MWS API, and any similar questions I have found are both old and unanswered.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that is a JSON formatted data record. JSON is slightly more compact than XML. JSON is not Python specific (in fact, it comes from Java), but there is a library in Python to convert such a record into a dictionary.

Comment: @jcoppens Do you have an idea of what library to use? Off the top of my head I tried something like `dict = json.loads(orders)` but that threw a `TypeError`.

Comment: I did not use mws, but I hope this will help you: (1) `order` is a python object, with its [datastructure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) inside (2) Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/mws.html) and the [mws unit-tests](https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/develop/tests/unit/mws) (3) boto already did all xml parsing for you, but you could use an [other api implementation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/) or query the aws xml api url manually.

Comment: @pez same problem. did you ever manage to find a good solution?